# The schrodinger equation is often called the "wave equation". Wave equation for what?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

The schrodinger equation is often called the "wave equation". it is a wave equation for what?

My try : for the Hamilton operator or ( energy operator)

Is it true ?

Comment: If you mean the first version that is usually shown to undergraduates, it is the propagation equation for a one particle quantum state, with the latter written as a position "wavefunction", *i.e.* probability amplitude as a function of the possible eigenvalues the position observable can have. The quantum state is always uniquely defined by the probability amplitude as a function of the possible values of a maximal set of commuting observables.

Answer (score 2):

The Schrödinger equation is always the time evolution equation ("equation of motion") for a system's [quantum state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_state). The equation is made in the [Schrödinger Picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_picture), where a system's state is held to evolve with time and observables are fixed. Contrast with the [Heisenberg Picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_picture), which is the other way around.

If you mean the first version of the equation $(-\frac{\hbar^2}{2\,m}\nabla^2 - V)\,\psi = i\,\hbar\,\partial_t\psi$ that is usually shown to undergraduates, or the one that chemists often write down, it is the propagation equation for a one particle quantum state, with the latter written as a position "wavefunction", i.e. probability amplitude as a function of the possible eigenvalues the position observable can have. The quantum state is always uniquely defined by the probability amplitude as a function of the possible values of a maximal set of commuting observables.